# vmware esxi - Changes to /etc/profile.local are not persistent but used to be

Tags: vmware, esxi

First off  I should state that I am an linux/esx noob...

I'm running esxi 6.7.0 I am trying to keep a persistent list of aliases for the esx shell so I am using /etc/profile.local to store them.

The problem I am running into now is that I want to make further changes to the list I have already created but every time I reboot the new changes are lost.

I can edit the file and cat it to verify the changes are saved but after every reboot my changes are lost. Only my original 4 aliases remain in profile.local with no way to add/change them.

Ive also tried added changes to  /etc/rc.local.d/local.sh but the same thing happens on reboot.

After some searching I learned about /sbin/auto-backup.sh and thinking that would help I also ran it but same issue.

There is a file called /etc/.#profile.local (which I did not create) but the content of it is just some comments and not the content of my few aliases in /etc/profile.local yet on each reboot my original 4 aliases are being restored.

Can someone tell me why I was once able to persist changes to  /etc/profile.local but now cannot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run /sbin/auto-backup.sh so that your modified file is properly saved in the "separate" tar archive (see below).  See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2001780 for more details.  Note that this script is only run hourly because inexpensive flash devices only support a bounded number of write cycles over a lifespan that can be measured in years.  If you're editing config files manually at the ESXi command prompt then you need to run this script manually but you shouldn't run it too often.  It is possible that if the script has been run too often in the past hour or day that further writes are blocked for awhile.

FWIW, the .# file is the original file and can never be deleted, but it is NOT the problem here.  You should only edit files that have the sticky bit set and when you do the new (edited) file is placed in a separate tar archive.  As part of ESXi boot the tar archives are unzipped and mapped into memory but NOT further processed (i.e., NO untar).  The archives are scanned in a deterministic order such that the aforementioned separate archive is scanned last.  Every time a file path is found it is inserted into the directory tree overwriting any previous path, so your modified file "wins" and gets used.  So your problem is that the first mod to the file is in the separate tar archive and your second mod to the file is not being captured.  Check the file modification date after you run the command mentioned above.

Those who are curious can peruse the first paper (author Olivier Cremel) in http://download3.vmware.com/software/vmw-tools/papers/VMTJ_issue_1.pdf for a more complete accounting of the original design of ESXi.